# Top navigation menu without dropdown

Tags: magento2.3, topmenu

Magento 2.3.3, custom theme based on Blank.

It's a very small store with only two categories. I want to display them in the top navigation menu without a dropdown menu. In other words, just a horizontal (inline) list of the two categories, at the top (not the left).

Where and what do I change to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by configuration setting `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Category Top Navigation > Maximal Depth`. Set it to `2`

More on depth level: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/navigation-top.html#counting-menu-levels.